# the value of my probability density function

Tags: probability

My formula is

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\big(t-\Delta t~\leq\text{log} \int_{0}^{t} \sigma_s^2 ~ds \leq t+\Delta t\big) & = \int_{t-\Delta t}^{t+\Delta t} f_{\text{log} \int_{0}^{t} \sigma_s^2 ~ds}~ (y) ~dy\\
& = \int_{t-\Delta t}^{t+\Delta t} f_{G}~ (y) ~dy\\
& = \int_{-\infty}^{t+\Delta t} f_{G}~ (y) ~dy-\int_{-\infty}^{t-\Delta t} f_{G}~ (y) ~dy\\
&=\int_{x}^{t+\Delta t} f_{G}~ (y) ~dy-\int_{x}^{t-\Delta t} f_{G}~ (y) ~dy
\end{align}

I am going to compute the probability $\mathbb{P}(\cdot)$. Therefore,
$\int_{x}^{t+\Delta t} f_{G}~ (y) ~dy$ and $\int_{x}^{t-\Delta t} f_{G}~ (y) ~dy$ can be greater than 1? Is it correct?

Thank you!

Comment: Not if $f_G(y)$ is some probability density function (and it seems to be).

Comment: the probability density function could be any non-negative number, but cdf has to lie in [0,1]? @drhab

Comment: Yes but if $f$ is a probability density then integrals like $\int^a_bf(x)dx$ are probabilities, so are elements of $[0,1]$.

Comment: you are right. I need to check my code again. @drhab